# read specific range of index from char buffer in fprinft using format specifiers in C

Tags: c

I will try to describe by problem and solution that I have as of now in detail. The solution I currently have is not optimal and I want to make it better.

Note: `char inputline[1024]` has no specific format, it can have strings of any format. The char inputline[1024] reads lines one by one from a file with thousands of lines. So that is why optimization is very important for me.

```
FILE *outfile = fopen("tests.txt", "w");
int start_index = 1; //index from where I want to write the characters from the inputline array to the file
int prev_index = start_index; //keep track of last character position written to file

char inputline[1024] = {"12044 This is the test String 2019 to 2025 is another test& and 2050"};
int loop_count = 6; // This can vary as I have just hardcoded a value here for testing
int i;        
for(i=0; i<loop_count; ++i)
{
    fprintf(outfile, "%c", inputline[prev_index + i]);
}
prev_index = prev_index + loop_count;// this keeps track of last position of character written to file at end
```

```
Sample input in char inputline[1024] = {"This is my day in 2020 1230023"}

Desired output in tests.txt: (for loop will loop 6 times as loop_count is 6)
his is
```

The issue is that I am reading `"%c"` and this is not very optimal and I want to use `%s` instead. But I am not able to understand how can I convert the `fprintf(outfile, "%c", inputline[prev_index + i]);` to use `"%s"` by specifying the `prev_index + i` in format specifier when writing to file as I only want to have the characters from `inputline[prev_index + i]` based on the loop to be written to the file.

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow. Can you provide a sample input and expected output?

Comment: @Xatenev Surely, let me update the question

Comment: I think I understood your problem, use `strncpy()` to create a substring of `inputline` starting from `start_index` to your suppposed to end index and make a single call to `fprintf()` with `%s` on the new string created from `strncpy()`

Comment: @Xatenev I updated the question. I am not sure on how to do it, make you should some sample code? Would it be efficient to use strncpy if I have to call the array a million times?

Comment: Check out https://ideone.com/S6Srtx and see if it helps you. I used the same variable names as you did so you know what is what  (even though names like loop_count don't make sense here anymore because theres no loop anymore.). *Note that you maybe have to `#include <string.h>` in your code.*

Comment: @Xatenev Surely, I will check it and let you know. May you also let me know whether it would it be efficient to use strncpy if I have to call the array a million times?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214835/discussion-between-anna-and-xatenev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the format specifier `%.*s` and pass in a `length`

https://ideone.com/UdC3aH

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int start_index = 1;
    int length = 6;
    char inputline[] = "This is my day in 2020 1230023";

    printf("%.*s\n", length, inputline + start_index); //  you can use fprintf(outfile, "%.*s", length, inputline + start_index); here
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> his is

Alternatively you could use `strncpy()` to make a substring and use that:

https://ideone.com/oyRJuG

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int start_index = 1;
    int loop_count = 6;
    char inputline[] = "This is my day in 2020 1230023";
    char substr[1024];

    strncpy ( substr, inputline + start_index, loop_count);
    substr[loop_count] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", substr); //  you can use fprintf(outfile, "%s", substr); here
    return 0;
}
```

*Note that you have to `#include <string.h>` in your code*

Output:

> his is